# Graphviz: how to insert two new linked nodes and minimize edge crossings?

Tags: python, graph-theory, graphviz, pygraphviz

I have the following graph [image: graph]:

As you can see, there are two natural clusters. I would like to figure out a way to separate these clusters into two graphs.

The key step, of course, is to compute the right split.  I would like to insert two nodes n1 & n2, link them e(n1, n2), and move them around, minimizing the number of edge crossings (of course fixing all nodes/edges exactly where they are).

Can anyone offer any help here?  I don't think graphviz has anything that enables me to do it.

Comment: +1 just for the impressive image :)

Comment: 1. Get Transparency International data for 88 countries; 
2. Create distance matrix between countries; create full graph.
3. One planet, two different worlds.

Comment: Just to be clear...do you already know the clustering of the graph and your question is how to get graphviz to layout the graph more cleanly, or is your first problem to (algorithmically) find the clustering and then assume that graphviz will produce a cleaner layout?

Comment: I want to automate the findings of these clusters, and look inside each one recursively.  Problem is graphviz doesn't offer me a way to peek into weighted edge crossings.

Comment: I read your question several times, but I don't understand what you're lookging for: Do you want two separate graphs? Or one graph with two clusters? Why exactly do you want to new nodes? And if you're fixing nodes/edges where they are right now - what is supposed to change?

Comment: I'm looking towards one graph with 2 clusters.  I figured out a better way: delete farthest edges until the graph becomes unconnected.  Simple, though probably not the fastest solution around.

Comment: If you want to automate finding the clusters, why don't you apply some module detection using hierarchical clustering and split at the top level? This should then give you the two main clusters (if this is really the underlying module structure). Thereby, you could also do the recursive analysis you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mingle two different tasks here: the one is **Analysis** of a graph, the other one is **Visualization** of the same.

Graphviz, as the name suggests, is a tool for visualization of graphs. Visualization can take many forms, typically one tries to "make it look good" by having those nodes close to each other that are connected, thus reducing the *visual* edge lengths. One can utilize some spring- or gravitational model to calculate optimal positions for all nodes. Other options include circular- or shell-layouts.

A certain visualization should not be the basis for the analysis of a graph. Graph properties, like average shortest path length or clustering coefficient, are independent of any visualization.

You say you want to "minimize the number of edge crossings". The number of edge crossings is a property of your visualization, not of your graph! It probably changes each time you let graphviz calculate the layout, even if the graph is unchanged. Who says that 2d is the only possible representation of your graph? Add just one dimension, and you won't have any edge crossing.

I'd recommend to concentrate on graph analysis. I don't know if you're aware of [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.com/). They have dozens of [Algorithms](http://networkx.github.com/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.html) to analyze your graph. Maybe the  *clustering* and *clique* sections are of interest to you.